# clearRect text canvas html5

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas text added in

```
    <canvas id="canvasOne" width="500" height="500">
       Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas.
    </canvas>
```

Javascript code:

```
    theCanvas = document.getElementById("canvasOne");
    var context = theCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var text = 'word';

    context.font = '16pt Calibri';
    context.fillStyle = '#333';

    var p0 = {x:x0,y:y0};
    var word = {x:p0.x, y:p0.y, velocityx: 0, velocityy:0};

    var lastTime = new Date().getTime();

    wrapText(context, text, p0.x, p0.y, maxWidth, lineHeight);
```

wrapText function():

```
    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, lineHeight) {
    var words = text.split(' ');
    var line = '';

    for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
      var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
      var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
      var testWidth = metrics.width;
      if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
        context.fillText(line, x, y);
        line = words[n] + ' ';
        y += lineHeight;
      }
      else {
        line = testLine;
      }
    }
    context.fillText(line, x, y);
  }
```

How can I use clearRect() for deleting only the word box?

```
      context.clearRect(word.x, word.y, word.x + offsetX, word.y + offsetY);
```

***UPDATE***

Partially solved with @Ozren Tkalčec Krznarić tips. But it don't erase the word completely, some part of the precedent is not erased (see the image above).
[image]

You can see the problem here: michelepierri.it/examples/canvas.html

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/yHnYh/6/

Thank you so much.

Comment: Your code is not complete. `context` is undefined. `word` is not used at all. `wrapText` is undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `wrapText()` call, use this:

```
context.clearRect(
  p0.x, 
  p0.y, 
  metrics.width > maxWidth ? metrics.width : maxWidth, 
  - text.split(' ').length * lineHeight);
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ozrentk/LVmAq/2/).

Note that:

- `p0.x` is your x coord (left boundary),
- `p0.y` is your y coord (bottom boundary),
- `metrics.width > maxWidth ? metrics.width : maxWidth` is your width, calculated as in the function itself,
- `- text.split(' ').length * lineHeight` is you negative height since text is accordingly aligned; it's calculated as in the function itself

Comment: it's not precise. the rect that clear the text is wider than necessary.

Comment: It depends how you want to use it - wider or more narrow calculation. Change code to `metrics.width < maxWidth ? metrics.width : maxWidth` to see the other option.

Comment: mmm now it's working better but it don't complete erase the word.
You can see the example here:  http://michelepierri.it/examples/canvas.html
and the probelm here http://michelepierri.it/examples/ax.png
thanks

Comment: Sorry, my provider is blocking your page. Use of jsFiddle and code copy/paste is encouraged on StackOverflow. However, it is working for you in the fiddle, right?

Comment: see my answer where I describe what is happening

Comment: This will not help. You are describing your problem as an answer. Please see my previous comment about code copy/paste and jsFiddle. Otherwise I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: here my jsfiddle... it not work, but if I paste it in a document it work... http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/yHnYh/6/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34522/discussion-between-ozren-tkalcec-krznaric-and-michele)